# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate not updating

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a boolean value to true on a button click. When I console.log the body of the response in the controller update method, the updated field is correct, but it is not changed in the database. Also the response is gigantic, so I'm thinking that something is wrong in what I am sending.  I have {new: true} set, but still no difference.  I'm doing something wrong here. Here is my code:

**Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const albumSchema = new Schema({
    albumId: { type: String },
    title: { type: String },
    artist: { type: String },
    tracks: { type: [String], required: true },
    year: { type: Number, required: true },
    thumbnail: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    listened: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

const Album = mongoose.model("Album", albumSchema);

module.exports = Album;
```

**React**

```
    changeStatus = (album) => {
      album.listened = true;
      API.updateAlbum(album)
    }
```

**API**

```
  updateAlbum: function(album) {
    return axios.put(`/api/albums/${album._id}`, album);
  },
```

**Routing**

```
router.route("/albums/:id").put(albumController.update)
```

**Mongoose Controller**

```
  update: function(req, res) {
    db.Album.findOneAndUpdate({ id: req.params.id }, req.body, { new: true })
      .then(dbAlbum => res.json(dbAlbum.body))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
```

Comment: you have to save the document after updating it.

Comment: @butthash3030 Instead of using `findOneAndUpdate()` and then saving the document, you can use `updateOne()` method. Also, this problem looks similar to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160223/mongoose-findoneandupdate-returns-updated-document-but-not-updated-in-database

Comment: @KarthickRam I opted for your solution and it worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the document after updating it

```
 update: function(req, res) {
    db.Album.findOneAndUpdate({ id: req.params.id }, req.body, { new: true })
      .then((dbAlbum)=>{
          dbAlbum.save()
            .then((saved)=>{
                res.json(dbAlbum)
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                res.status(422).json(err)
            })

      })
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }
```